# Bind custom event handler after ajax load

Tags: ajax, bind, lightbox, jquery

Specifically I'm looking to bind lightbox to a specific element. Normally I would just do this: `$('a.lightbox').lightBox();` but that isn't working since I'm doing some loading with AJAX. Looking at the jQuery API I found `.bind()` and `.live()` but I'm not getting anything when I do `$('a.lightbox').bind('lightBox')` after the AJAX `.load()` call.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a callback function that handles that.

```
$("#div").load(url, {}, function(){ $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); });
```

Bind isn't going to help you, as the event isn't getting an event fired on it.

Comment: Perfect. Works great, guess I didn't have to use .bind() after all. Also, that's why I was confused with bind - I knew that it required a function from the API but I didn't have any such function.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to bind to an element higher up in the dom and check the target type. Such as:

```
$('#div').bind('click', function (event) {
    target = $(event.target);
    if (target.hasClass('lightbox')) {
        // do stuff here
    }
});
```

Just don't go too far up or you'll be catching way too many clicks.